# Atom code editor Discover tag in Autocomplete

Tags: atom-editor

Atom code editor shows a tag called Discover when typing a Div tag.

What does this tag do? Or is it something from the crazy house?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a tag, it's just a word. It might exist in the same document you're editing, or another document in another tab.